# Does ';' slow python program?

Tags: python, performance

I'm used to Java and Javascript, so I hate not using ';' at the end of a line. Does it slow a python program being an interpreted language?

Comment: Technically yes, because the parser has to read the character, but it is such a small amount that it won't be measurable.

Comment: If "Yes" is enough to prevent you from using it, then Yes.

Comment: It slows it down as much as adding a new line to separate statements in JavaScript

Comment: If you use a new language, adapt to it. Otherwise, your future co-workers will *hate* you.

Comment: If you're worried about semicolons imagine what happens with comments and formatting. The last thing you should be optimizing for is parsing speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't slow down Python, no more than adding an extra space to the line slows it down.

Use Python the way it's meant to be used. Get used to its syntax.